# msal - await acquireTokenSilent

Tags: angular, asynchronous, async-await, azure-ad-msal, synchronous

I'm implementing `msal-v1` in my `angular 7` application and I would like to implement my `own interceptor` where I get access token by calling `acquireTokenSilent` and then attaching the token to the http headers.

as the acquireTokenSilent is `asynchronous`, the token in the http headers is always `empty`, I need the application to `wait until retrieve token and then set the headers`.

**First approach**:

```
const acquireToken = async () => {
        let token = "";
        const authRequest = {
          scopes: ["user.read"],
        };
        try {
          const resp = await this.authService.acquireTokenSilent(authRequest);
          token = resp.accessToken;
        } catch (err) {
          if (err instanceof InteractionRequiredAuthError) {
            await this.authService.acquireTokenRedirect(authRequest);
          }
        }
        return token;
      };
      
      return next.handle(
        httpRequest.clone({
          setHeaders: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${this.token}`,
          },
        })
      );
```

**Second Approach**:

```
const authRequest = {
            scopes: ["clientID/.default"],
          };

      var token = this.getAuthenticationToken(authRequest);

      return next.handle(
        httpRequest.clone({
          setHeaders: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
          },
        })
      );
    }

------------------

public getAuthenticationToken(authRequest): Promise<string> {
    
    return this.authService
      .acquireTokenSilent(authRequest)
      .then((token) => {
        console.log("Got silent access token: ", token);
        return token.accessToken;
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log("Could not silently retrieve token from storage.", error);
        return this.authService
          .acquireTokenPopup(authRequest)
          .then((token) => {
            console.log("Got popup access token: ", token);
            return token.accessToken;
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.log("Could not retrieve token from popup.", error);
            this.authService.acquireTokenRedirect(authRequest);
            return Promise.resolve("");
          });
      });
  }
```

but nothing seems to work, can anyone help me to make the acquireTokenSilent as synchronous.
The reason I'm doing this approach is because I need to make the user to stay active with silent renew token in the background.

Answer (score 1):

I went through this same problem recently, this worked for me, the problem itself in my understanding is the interceptor call being a synchronous process calling the promise that asynchronously.

[code here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NuZCt.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).